# how to handle SESSION object in different extension of the same address in php

Tags: php, session

I am using PHP to store Product Cart and User login Session in PHP SESSION object. Everything working perfectly but there is only one problem occurs every time.

If any one create a session in http://www.example.com/
and if the url change to 

http://example.com or https://www.example.com or https://example.com
then the session is gets vanished and again if the url become 
http://www.example.com  the SESSION appears again.

How to solve this problem. I can not maintain the url and the session because users are redirected to my site from different websites.

Comment: I know what u mean, and many websites fix it by rewriting the url from example.com to www.example.com and reversed. Basically I think that it is the only possible solution

Comment: use htaccess and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

Use .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this code will add **www** to your domain, so the user is not able to accesss example.com. He will be instantly redirected to www.example.com

Comment: thanks for your comments and answer. I am not used to .htaccess. Can you suggest me a link begin with .htaccess. Thanks

Comment: basically there is nothing difficult and u don't have to worry about htaccess at all... if u just copy the code I gave u and add RewriteEngine On on the top of your file, it will work perfectly

Comment: how to add RewriteEngine  ?

Comment: I will update my question. You just need to add this code to your .htaccess file